# How to connect to Cloud-SQL from Cloud Function in Go?

Tags: postgresql, go, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

For a project i'm trying to connection a cloud function to a cloud sql database setup as described in [this quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/quickstart).

The function is configured in the same region, the service account has the Role `Cloud SQL-Client`. I called the function through my computer like this:

```sh
gcloud functions call <function-name> --region=<region> --data '{"recipient":"hello","requester":"hello","message":"test"}'
```

The connection to the function is working, it seems like just the authentication to the database doesn't work but i don't get where i failed.

I checked the password, user and connection name multiple times, reset the password and it still doesn't work.
I found the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36388165) related to connecting cloud functions to cloud sql.

I tried surrounding the password in the `dsn`-string with single-quotes just to be sure escaping of characters in the password isn't a problem.

I also checked the environment variables coming in and they are the ones i entered in the configuration.

The function just pings the database for test purposes:

```golang
package receiver

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    // Import Postgres SQL driver
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

// Receives a message and stores it
func Receive(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    connectionName := os.Getenv("POSTGRES_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME")
    dbUser         := os.Getenv("POSTGRES_USER")
    dbPassword     := os.Getenv("POSTGRES_PASSWORD")
    dsn            := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password='%s' host=/cloudsql/%s dbname=messages", dbUser, dbPassword, connectionName)

    var err error
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Could not open db: %v \n", err)
    }

    // Only allow 1 connection to the database to avoid overloading
    db.SetMaxIdleConns(1)
    db.SetMaxOpenConns(1)
    defer db.Close()

    if pingerror := db.Ping(); pingerror != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Failed to ping database: %s \n", pingerror)
        return
    }
}
```

The variable `POSTGRES_INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` is formatted as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#functions_sql_postgres-go) as `ProjectID:Region:InstanceID`.

Expected is a success message or no error and i'm actually getting this message:

```sh
pq: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Note: I also created a function containing the demo code from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/functions/sql/postgres/postgres.go) with my sql database settings and the error is the same. It seems like i missed some step while setting up the user or sql instance. But i can't find out which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels strange to answer my own question but here it is: For some reason connecting with the `postgres` user doesn't work. Finally i created a new database user for the function and a password containing only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Hey, good job on finding the solution to your question. As soon as you can, please mark it as solution to give more visibility to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The unix socket at `/cloudsql/{connectionName}` is only provided in the GCF runtime. When running locally, you either need change your connection string or use the [Cloud SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy) to simulate a unix socket at the same path.

Comment: I tested with the emulator and proxy already and hat no success and i already created the function in the gcloud console and am still receiving the same error.